# Can Bayesian reasoning be simplified to classical logic

Tags: logic, reference-request, bayesian

Classical logic is a reasonably good way of modelling rational thinking but it has limitations, as illustrated by the [lottery paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lottery_paradox), the [preface paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preface_paradox), and others. One way of overcoming these limitations is by introducing a probabilistic element into logic or even going all the way to Bayesian reasoning.

I was wondering whether there has been any attempt to bridge from one to the other? Maybe under some assumptions (e.g. very high probabilities) we can simplify Bayesian reasoning in a way that the end result is classical logic?

**Note:** In a way, I am looking for a logical equivalent to what happens in electromagnetism (and other fields, of course) where you can take the very general Maxwell equations, simplify them for the specific case of electrical circuits, and end up with Kirchoff equations, which are not as general but are much easier to compute in the context (i.e. circuits) that grants certain assumptions.

Comment: I'm not sure this is what you were looking for, but [Jaynes' book](https://www.amazon.com/Probability-Theory-Science-T-Jaynes/dp/0521592712) starts with clear cut (logical) true false statements and talks about how probability (specifically Bayesian reasoning) is an extension of that.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have had a look at the preface and it does not seem to be what I am looking for. Jaynes says that probability theory / Bayesian reasoning is "an extension of logic", but only by waving the hands. I did not see an algebraic proof of the kind of "if we take these assumptions" or "if we take these parameters to the limit", then we get something like classical logic.

Comment: In other words, Jaynes seems to see probability theory as something that should take the place of classical logic as a model of rational thinking but not as a generalisation of it in the same ways as Maxwell equations are a generalisation of Kirchoff's (which is what I am looking for).

Comment: Re: Lottery Paradox article: Contrary to a claim there, it is NOT rational to "accept the proposition that ticket 1 of the lottery will not win." It might win. Unlikely $\neq$ Impossible.

Comment: That is exactly why it is a paradox, @DanChristensen, at least as far as classical logic is considered a model for rational thinking and/or behaviour. ;-)

Comment: Classical logic does not conclude that no ticket will win. That's just a mental error that I would think few would be prone to make.

Comment: @sergut Jaynes presents a derivation due to Cox of the laws of probability from a collection of desiderata that include corresponding to classical logic in the extreme case. Regardless, it's a completely straightforward exercise to show the laws of probability in the finite, discrete case give rise to the usual (sound and complete) model of classical propositional logic if all atomic propositions/events are required to have probability 0 or 1. Jaynes' formulation of the laws of probability make this more direct than the "usual" axiomatization, but it is easy either way.

Comment: @DanChristensen The article begins with 2 premises. It then establishes a contraction at the end. This implies that at least one of the premises is false. Classical logic does in fact conclude that no ticket will win *given these premises*. It also implies that a single ticket *will win* as well. Hence the contradiction.

Comment: @user400188 What 2 premises exactly? It isn't clear to me. The premise that ticket 1 cannot win is clearly false. Not sure what the other premise might be.

Comment: @DanChristensen They are "one ticket will win" and "an event is very likely only if the probability of it occurring is greater than 0.99" .
The paradox is meant to illustrate the contradiction that arises when events that are very likely are taken to be true.

Comment: @user400188 No problem with the first premise. The second is just nonsense. No contradiction. No paradox.

Comment: @user400188: Did you see my answer? It basically explains what you've stated in your comment, but I don't understand why someone randomly downvoted it yesterday...

Answer (score 0):

It is a misconception that classical logic has known flaws or limitations when dealing with any so-called 'paradoxes'. The error is not at all in classical logic but in the incorrect application of it.

---

In particular, classical logic yields the **inescapable conclusion** that one cannot make nonsensical claims like "If P has at least 99% likelihood then P is true.". Also, a proper grasp of classical logic would immediately tell you where the error lies in the invalid reasoning employed in the two 'paradoxes' you cited. I shall explicitly show the mistake now. Consider the following:

> (1) For every statement P in the book, the author has high confidence that P is true.
>
> (2) The author has high confidence that, for every statement P in the book, P is true.

It is obvious that (1) and (2) are not equivalent, and that claiming their equivalence is akin to an invalid quantifier switch. Why do I use "has high confidence" in place of "believes"? Because it is indeed the case that the choice of the **ambiguous** word "believes" hides the fact that it is based on some threshold of confidence. Therefore the 'paradox' is just nonsense for the ordinary meaning of "believe".

If the author only believes things that he/she is 100% confident about, then (1) and (2) are actually equivalent, but this also destroys the 'paradox'; if one of the statements in the book is false, then in the first place he/she had no valid reason to believe (have 100% confidence) that it is true, **unless** he/she is irrational (from the viewpoint of **classical** logic).

---

Furthermore, all of (modern) probability theory can be built in ZFC set theory, which is the current conventional foundations and also a classical set theory.

---

That said, one can consider extensions of classical logic with [generalized quantifiers](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/generalized-quantifiers). In some parts of complexity theory there have also been some attempts to simplify classifications and arguments involving atypical quantifiers such as [this paper regarding "most"](http://corelab.ntua.gr/courses/grad-algo/material/Quantifiers.pdf). Still, these could be considered classical, since they are easily handled in classical set theory. The advantage of these generalized quantifiers is in deductive facility and intuitiveness and replacement of set-theoretical notions.

Comment: Who is the downvoter who downvotes without reason? If you specify what is wrong, I will fix any errors. If not, the downvote is meaningless.